# asp.net razor: showing an alert from the browser overrides whole page content

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

I am trying to find out whether a user is already registered at our backend via his email:

```
 var user = await new RemoteUserService().GetItemByEmail(emailAddress);

 if(user.Count() != 0)
 {
    // email exists already
    await Response.WriteAsync("<p>hi mom</p><script>alert('This email is already in use')</script>");
    return RedirectToPage("CreateAccount");
 }
```

This is working code, and when the user is already registered I am seeing an alert in my browser writing "This email is already in use". However, the page now completely changes to white. So basically the page is gone after that. When I hit "ok" on my alert I see a little" "hi mom" in the top corner, but still, the page is override by what I put into the WriteAsync(). I am also not redirected to my page, it just stays there.[image]

I also cannot hit refresh, as this will just show the alert again.
If I wanted to go back to my original page I would have to remove the CreateAccount?handler=Button_Login part of the URL.

If I however where to remove the whole WriteAsync() part, the page would reload just fine, but without any notification to the user over that his email was already registered.

How can I show a alert from the controller and still either reload the page or not leave the page at all (I know the second option probably isnt possible).

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to alert from the controller? In my opinion, you can just return `This email is already in use` in controller, then in ajax success method alert this message and redirect to the new page.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, You can alert the message and redirect to a new page in ajax success method, Please refer to this simple demo.

**View**

```
<input type="number" id="input" />
<button type="button" id="btn">Submit</button>

@section Scripts{
    <script>
        document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function(){
            let input = document.getElementById('input').value
            var postData = {
                'Id': input,
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: "Post",
                url: "/Home/Case",
                data: postData,
                success: function (res) {
                    if(res.state==200){
                        alert(res.message)
                        location.href = '/home/index'
                    }else{
                        alert(res.message)
                        location.href = '/home/privacy'
                    }
                }
                
            })
        }
    </script>
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Case(int Id)
        {
            if (Id<=0)
            {
                //do some action....
                ReturnMessage returnMessage = new ReturnMessage()
                {
                    state = 200,
                    message = "success"
                };
                return Ok(returnMessage);
            }
            else
            {
                //do some action.....
                ReturnMessage returnMessage2 = new ReturnMessage()
                {
                    state = 400,
                    message = "This email is already in use"
                };
                return Ok(returnMessage2);
            }

        }
```

**Gif Demo**

[image]

Hope this answer can give you some help.